# Why the vertical line in the tabularray table exceeds the horizontal line?

Tags: pdftex, tabularray

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c|c|c},hlines}
\hline
A & B & C \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} A & B1 & C1 \\
                   & B2 & C2 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is my misuse of tabularray causing this result?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be related to `\SetCell[r=2]{c}`. If you add another table row with cells that span only one row you get the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis When I need to add or delete rows/columns, it is convenient to use `\SetCell`. It's a pity that there seems to be something wrong with `\SetCell` so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a similar issue reported here: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/141

The following is a quick workaround:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c|c|c},
  rowspec={||Q|Q|Q||},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{c}, % multirow
  vline{2} = {1}{-}{belowpos=0}, % workaround
}
  A & B  & C   \\
  A & B1 & C1 \\
    & B2 & C2 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]