# Color of hline is going over vline with tabularray

Tags: tabularray

With tabularray, I'm trying to reach the following result:
[image: Expected result]

However, when doing it with tabularray:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Accept different input encodings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Standard package for selecting font encodings.
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} %Driver-independent color extensions.

\usepackage{tabularray} %Typeset Tabulars and Arrays with LATEX3
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables

% Solid colors used by custom
\definecolor{customPink}{RGB}{255,000,255}
\definecolor{customLightBlue}{RGB}{034,181,255}
\definecolor{customYellow}{RGB}{255,194,000}
\definecolor{customDarkBlue}{RGB}{000,113,188}

\definecolor{customShadePink1}{RGB}{233,099,253}
\definecolor{customShadePurple1}{RGB}{155,086,244}
\definecolor{customShadeBlue1}{RGB}{087,129,242}

\definecolor{customGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{customGreyLight}{RGB}{243,243,234}

\definecolor{customGreyHeaderTable}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{customGreyRowTable}{RGB}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
                    hline{1,Z} = {1pt,solid},
                    hline{2} = {1pt,solid,customGrey},
                    hline{3,Y} = {customGreyLight},
                    vline{1,Z} = {1pt,solid},
                    vline{2-Y} = {customGreyLight},
                    columns  = {l},
                    row{1}  = {bg=customGreyHeaderTable, fg=customShadePink1},
                    row{2-Z}= {bg=customGreyRowTable, fg=customGrey}
                }
        \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Comment} & \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Reviewer} \\
        0.1 & 16-04-2023 & Creation of the document & ... & ... \\
        &  &  &  &  \\
        &  &  &  &  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

It gives the following ouput:
[image: current result]

The horizontal lines are going over the first and last vertical lines and I would like the opposite to highlight the outside borders.

Within the table, It can remain like it is i.e. I want the hline color to have priority over the inside vline colors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SE. But, your code is not compilable. I don't know about `customGreyLight`, and I couldn't find it in `xcolor`. Start with `\documentclass` and  and ends with `\end[document}`

Comment: Yes, I just provided the sample of the code that was interesting me. I didn't put the full code. I'll update the description.

Comment: Unrelated: I don't think that `8pt` is a valid option to the `report` class. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473838/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629004/47927) you can add the options `rightpos=0` and `leftpos=0` to the relevant `hline`s to have the horizontal lines start after the first vertical lines and end before the last one. The other vertical lines would, however, still be printed over the horizontal lines:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{customPink}{RGB}{255,000,255}
\definecolor{customShadePink1}{RGB}{233,099,253}
\definecolor{customGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{customGreyLight}{RGB}{243,243,234}
\definecolor{customGreyHeaderTable}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{customGreyRowTable}{RGB}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        hline{1,Z} = {1pt, solid},
        hline{2} = {1pt, solid, customGrey, leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
        hline{3,Y} = {customGreyLight, leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
        vline{1,Z} = {1pt, solid},
        vline{2-Y} = {customGreyLight},
        columns = {l},
        row{1} = {bg=customGreyHeaderTable, fg=customShadePink1},
        row{2-Z}= {bg=customGreyRowTable, fg=customGrey}
    }
    \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Comment} & \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Reviewer} \\
    0.1 & 16-04-2023 & Creation of the document & ... & ... \\
    &  &  &  &  \\
    &  &  &  &  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

To have the thick grey horizontal line cover the thin vertical lines inside the tabular, you need to split it up into three parts essentially, resulting in a more complex setup:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{customPink}{RGB}{255,000,255}
\definecolor{customShadePink1}{RGB}{233,099,253}
\definecolor{customGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{customGreyLight}{RGB}{243,243,234}
\definecolor{customGreyHeaderTable}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{customGreyRowTable}{RGB}{250,250,250}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        hline{1,Z} = {1pt, solid},
        hline{2} = {1}{1pt, solid, customGrey, leftpos=0},
        hline{2} = {2-Y}{1pt, solid, customGrey},
        hline{2} = {Z}{1pt, solid, customGrey, rightpos=0},
        hline{3,Y} = {customGreyLight, leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
        vline{1,Z} = {1pt, solid},
        vline{2-Y} = {customGreyLight},
        columns = {l},
        row{1} = {bg=customGreyHeaderTable, fg=customShadePink1},
        row{2-Z}= {bg=customGreyRowTable, fg=customGrey}
    }
    \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Comment} & \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Reviewer} \\
    0.1 & 16-04-2023 & Creation of the document & ... & ... \\
    &  &  &  &  \\
    &  &  &  &  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is a way to create that table with `{NiceTabualar}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Standard package for selecting font encodings.
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\definecolor{customShadePink1}{RGB}{233,099,253}

\definecolor{customGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{customGreyLight}{RGB}{243,243,234}

\definecolor{customGreyHeaderTable}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{customGreyRowTable}{RGB}{250,250,250}


\begin{document}

\color{customGrey}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lllll}[hvlines,rules/color=customGreyLight,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{customGreyHeaderTable}{1}
  \rowcolor{customGreyRowTable}{2-*}
\Body
  \RowStyle[color=customShadePink1]{\bfseries}
      Version & Date & Comment & Author & Reviewer \\
      0.1 & 16-04-2023 & Creation of the document & ... & ... \\
      &  &  &  &  \\
      &  &  &  &  \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [line width=1pt, color=customGrey] (2-|1) -- (2-|last) ; 
  \tikz \draw [line width=1pt,color=black] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I think * in `\rowcolor{customGreyRowTable}{2-*}` causes an error.

Comment: @pascal974: I can compile without error...

Comment: shame on me, I didn't check that there was a new version (I had tested with `nicematrix 6.17` and also on `texlive.net`). With 6.26a there are no compilation errors)